# Unable to find "org name" and "artifact id" of client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar on Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-ide, ivy

I need to download the dependency jar files from maven through Apache Ivy.jar; I am unable to find it's org and artifact ID.

It's the ivy.xml by default the ivy command will download the dependency files to the same directory. these all are being downloaded but I got no information on client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar  and it's missing and the application is getting stuck at compile time.

```
  <ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="myrepo" module="demo"/>
<configurations>
        <conf name="specificFolder"  description="add jar to web-inf/lib folder"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="cglib" name="cglib-nodep" rev="3.2.4"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" rev="1.10"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-exec" rev="1.3"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="commons-io" name="commons-io" rev="2.5"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.2"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="cssparser" name="cssparser" rev="0.9.4"   conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="10.0.1" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.0" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.hamcrest" name="hamcrest-core" rev="1.3" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlunit" name="htmlunit" rev="2.26" conf="specificFolder->master"/>   
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlunit" name="htmlunit-core-js" rev="2.26" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="htmlunit-driver" rev="2.26" conf="specificFolder->master"/> 
    <dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="4.5.3" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpcore" rev="4.4.6" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpmime" rev="4.5.3" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="javax.servlet-api" rev="3.1.0" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty" name="jetty-io" rev="9.4.1.v20170120" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty" name="jetty-util" rev="9.4.1.v20170120" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="net.java.dev.jna" name="jna" rev="4.1.0" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="net.java.dev.jna" name="jna-platform" rev="4.1.0" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlunit" name="neko-htmlunit" rev="2.25" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="com.codeborne" name="phantomjsdriver" rev="1.4.0" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.w3c.css" name="sac" rev="1.3" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="xalan" name="serializer" rev="2.7.2" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty.websocket" name="websocket-api" rev="9.4.3.v20170317" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty.websocket" name="websocket-client" rev="9.4.3.v20170317" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty.websocket" name="websocket-server" rev="9.4.3.v20170317" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="xalan" name="xalan" rev="2.7.2" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="xerces" name="xercesImpl" rev="2.11.0" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
    <dependency org="xml-apis" name="xml-apis" rev="1.4.01" conf="specificFolder->master"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: There it is, with a few more details.

Comment: according to simon stewart "The class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver is in the client-combined-3.3.1-nodeps.jar."

Comment: Could anybody dare to answer instead of down voting ????

Comment: This might help point you in the right direction for what [dependencies you should be referencing] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310996/selenium-webdriver-3-0-1-actions-class-missing-from-selenium-api-3-0-1-jar-from). `selenium-java` should include packages that include `client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar`

Comment: I have tried both selenium-java and selenium-remote-driver the problem is still there.

Comment: Try removing all of your selenium references, and start over just including `selenium-java`. Then add any other references as necessary. It sounds like you might be running into messy conflicts

Comment: Actually I have went through google group as well on selenium, there when I need to execute a suite i need to have driver executables and it's not included in the above mentioned jars. I will need to have the executable and then will have to set it's path as system property.

Answer (score 1):

Ivy and Maven clients by default download their jars from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org). which happily has a search interface.

Searching for the class "[org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22%20org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver%22)" yields the following dependency, which you should add to your ivy file:

```
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-firefox-driver" rev="3.3.1" />
```